# Network-Wide Process Communication/Coordination

Tags: linux, windows, networking, service

I am looking for a way to connect processes on multiple systems in potentially multiple locations. An event bus or message queue seems the ideal way to do this, but I have not been able to find an existing solution which implements something like this. Let me give some examples of what I am trying to do...

1. A message comes into my email server to support@example.com. I would like to kick off a job on the server that runs my issue management software to POP the mail from that account.
2. One of my team makes a push to our internal Git repository. I would like to have my chat bot notify the #developers room of this push and have my build server start a build.
3. My deployment system finishes a production deployment. I would like to have my issue management system mark all issues in the deploy as deployed and my chat bot to notify the #operations room that production has been updated.

I am aware I can build scripts to directly affect these changes (which is what I have been doing), but I would prefer a decoupled solution. Having to modify my Git post-receive hook every time I add a new application which needs to know when a push has been made seems odd for a guy who spends most of his time writing software. Decoupling would make for much easier maintenance and I see no good reason to have all the components of my network actually have to know about each other. I run a mix of Windows Server 2008 R2 and CentOS 6.x/7.x so something cross-platform would be nice.

Ideally I would have a daemon on each system which listens to a central message queue and lets me define jobs or scripts to react to certain events. I would also need some way of injecting an event into the queue from the command line or a script. I am really open to anything that achieves some decoupling. The only solution I can think is to try to use an AMQP server and wire everything up myself.

If something like this already exists and I missed it, I do apologise. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.